# Oracle query with sum() in the where clause

Tags: oracle

I have a table which consists two columns amount and description. Now i need something like
Select description from tab where sum(amount) > 5000
Which is not possible i guess. Is there any custom method to get this done ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try something like:

```
select description, sum(amount)
from tab
group by description
having sum(amount) > 5000
;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I need one more help. Accounts table contains acno and acid. Tab consists of acid. To group the above query based on acno i should write.                    Select acno,description,sum(amount) from tab,accounts where accounts.acid=tab.acid group by acno,description having sum(amount) > 5000. ???